# Rails4: Why insert a new record when delete a image uploaded with carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

When I delete a image which was uploaded using carrierwave, a new record is inserted at the same time.
How can I avoid inserting a new record?

`article` has many `photo`.

```
sqlite> .schema photos
CREATE TABLE "photos" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "articl_id" integer, "image" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetim);
```

The id 93 and 94 exist before deleting photo.

```
sqlite> select * from photos;
93|27|DSCN0722_070.JPG|2014-09-07 01:59:03.320092|2014-09-07 01:59:03.320092
94|27|DSCN0725_070.JPG|2014-09-07 01:59:03.332093|2014-09-07 01:59:03.332093
```

When I checked check box to delete id=93 and submitted, id=93 is deleted I expected but a new record id=95 is inserted with no image, I'm not sure.

```
sqlite> select * from photos;  
94|27|DSCN0725_070.JPG|2014-09-07 01:59:03.332093|2014-09-07
95|27||2014-09-07 02:01:58.634119|2014-09-07 02:01:58.634119
```

If there are 3 records, it works (a new record isn't inserted).
But there are 2 records like above, it occurs.

Thanks in advance.

log/development.log

```
.
.
Started PATCH "/articles/27" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-07 11:01:58 +0900
Processing by ArticlesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"笨・, "authenticity_token"=>"xxx=", "article"=>{"category_id"=>"1379", "photos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"article_id"=>"27", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"93"}, "1"=>{"article_id"=>"27", "_destroy"=>"0", "id"=>"94"}, "2"=>{"article_id"=>"27"}}, "content"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"譖ｴ譁ｰ縺吶ｋ", "id"=>"27"}
[1m[35mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'xxxx' LIMIT 1
[1m[36mArticle Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."user_id" = ? AND "articles"."id" = 27 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
[1m[35mArticle Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", "27"]]
[1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
[1m[35mPhoto Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."article_id" = ? AND "photos"."id" IN (93, 94)  [["article_id", 27]]
[1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."article_id" = ?[0m  [["article_id", 27]]
#Delete id=93
[1m[35mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = ?  [["id", 93]]
#Why new record is inserted?
[1m[36mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "photos" ("article_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)[0m  [["article_id", 27], ["created_at", Sun, 07 Sep 2014 02:01:58 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sun, 07 Sep 2014 02:01:58 UTC +00:00]]
[1m[35m (5.0ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 48ms (ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

\models\article.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
    validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :category_id, presence: true
    validate :check_for_at_least_image

    def build_images
      (3 - self.photos.size).times {self.photos.build}
    end

    def check_for_at_least_image
      errors.add(:image, "select...") if self.photos.size <= 0
    end

end
```

\models\photo.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
   mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

\view\articles\edit.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
        <%= render 'shared/article_form' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

\view\shared\ _article_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :category_id %>
    <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
      <%= p.hidden_field :article_id %>
      <div class="photo">
      <% if p.object.image and p.object.image.file %>
        <%= image_tag p.object.image.thumb.url %>
        <p>article:<%= @article.id %></p>
        <p>photo:<%= p.object.id %></p>
        <%= p.hidden_field :image_cache if p.object.image_cache %>
        <label><%= p.check_box :_destroy %>delete</label>
      <% end %>
      <%= p.file_field :image %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Enter content..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

\controllers\articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:update, :destroy]
.
.
  def new
    @article = Article.new
    @category  = Category.find(params[:category])
    @article.category_id = @category.id
    3.times { @article.photos.build }
  end

  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
    if @article.save
      flash[:success] = "article created!"
      redirect_to current_user #root_url
    else
        @article.build_images
       render 'new'
    end
  end
.
.
  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.build_images
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:content, :category_id, photos_attributes: [:id, :article_id, :image, :image_cache, :_destroy])
    end
.
.
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you look at your logs **attributes for other image are still passed to the update action when you are deleting a image***

```
"article"=>{"category_id"=>"1379", "photos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"article_id"=>"27", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"93"}, "1"=>{"article_id"=>"27", "_destroy"=>"0", "id"=>"94"}, "2"=>{"article_id"=>"27"}}, "content"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"譖ｴ譁ｰ縺吶ｋ", "id"=>"27"}
```

**FIX**

You have two options:

a. ***Don't build a new image in edit action:***.

You are ***building a new image in your edit action which is then passed on to your update method when you submit your form*** so you can remove this line in edit action and fix your issue

```
 @article.build_images
```

b. ***Use a Proc instead of blank_all:***

If you look at your code you have

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

You are using reject_if: :all_blank instead of a Proc, if you look at [`docs`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for), it says

> Passing :all_blank instead of a Proc will create a proc that will reject a record where all the attributes are blank excluding any value for _destroy.

***and in your case attributes are still being passed for other image so it's creating a new image for you. You can use a Proc to eliminate this:***

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['image'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
```

Comment: Thank you for your always advice. I expect three `<%= p.file_field :image %>` are always displayed despite the number of images I select. When I tried "remove build_images", `<%= p.file_field :image %>` are displayed according to the number of the selected files. For example, two `<%= p.file_field :image %>` are displayed after deleting a image from three images. So I tried "use a proc instead of blank_all". It seemed to work, but didn't. When I delete all images, no error appears. What I want to do is for users to select at least one image (up to 3 images) and to enter f.text_area.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue i think i solved this issue in your earlier question when you were using proc for rejecting blank images, didn't i?

Comment: Thank you for your help the other day. Yes, you could solve my question. But I found out it works only in `create` action, it doesn't work in `update` action. Aothogh it may be nothing to do with the question this time, it would be appreciated if you could advise. I tried some of the code, but they didn't turn out right.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue why are you using update method? This seems to be deprecated http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class Try update_attributes. Also post your logs when you try to update it. It'll be better if you ask another question and close this one so if someone else is also having same problem or in future may have same problem could benefit from it

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The reason why I use `update` method is that I learned Rails by reference to [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book). So I didn't know `update` is depreciated. As you advised, I close this question and ask [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819209/rails4-to-check-for-no-image-uploaded-with-carrierwave-is-not-working-when-dele). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are building images for three times always in your article model. When you try to delete image from two images there is also a blank object present for photo that is created by build and when you submit in update action this part `@article.update(article_params)` add a blank object and also delete an object for photo table. That's why you are getting this issue. Check your params before updating record for photo will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It would be appreciated if you could be a little more specific about checking params before updating record.